# Remove video from youtube watch later by python gdata library

Tags: python, youtube

How can I remove video from youtube watch later by python gdata library?
I check API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?hl=en#Retrieving_watch_later_playlist,
and try its method:
**Deleting a video from the playlist:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_later/VIDEO_ID.**

via python gdata library

```
playlist_uri = u"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_later"
playlist_entry_id = videoID .............(Does watch later have playlist_entry_id??)
response = yt_service.DeletePlaylistVideoEntry(playlist_uri,
                                               playlist_entry_id)
=>Error: Bad request
```

or

```
playlist_uri = u"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_later/%s" % videoID
response = yt_service.Delete("playlist_uri)
=>Error: Bad request
```

Both Failed!

Is there any other way to get it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `DeletePlaylistVideoEntry(playlist_uri, playlist_entry_id` is the way to go, what's your error message say or what happens? And why would this NOT work? Give us clues and code plese. Also, note that `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_later/` appears to be an **invalid URI**.

Comment: Dear Torxed, I follow 'watch later feed' to coding, but I don't konw how to use the API defined uri "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_later/<VIDEO_ID>". Besides, if use DeletePlaylistVideoEntry(playlist_uri, playlist_entry_id) work, what are playlist_uri, playlist_entry_id in watch later?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: First of all you need more code than just these two lines, you need to initate `YouTubeService`, then you need to find the playlist and what it's actually called (not sure watch_later is correct, it's probably just an alias for teh actual playlist.. but anyway) check out this reference library and see if it helps (you can form your own requests): https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists

Answer (score 0):

After testing & trying again and again, the code which can successfully perform in my develop environment is very different form Youtube document: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?hl=en#Retrieving_watch_later_playlist.

For Reference Purposes Only.
1. Use playlist_entry_id instead of VIDEO_ID:
   - How to get playlist_entry_id for each video in watch later?
     . General playlist: entry.id.text.split('/')[-1]
     . Watch later playlist: **entry.id.text.split('watch_later:')[-1]**
2. API URL need to add **'?v=2'**
My Ans:
   playlist_uri = https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_later/**playlist_entry_id?v=2**
   self.__ytService.Delete(playlist_uri)